# Unable to start Apache Tomcat 8.5.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache2, tomcat8

I have installed the following distribution of Tomcat: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.5.4/bin/apache-tomcat-8.5.4.tar.gz

I have followed this instruction step by step: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

And I have started the service by using the command `sudo systemctl start tomcat`, I have got the following error:

```
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Make user 'tomcat' owner of the whole tomcat directory using below command:

```
cd /opt && sudo chown -R tomcat tomcat/
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I forgot to change the value for `JAVA_HOME` in `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` to match my servers `JAVA_HOME`. Changed it and everything is up and running fine.

Comment: I my case the problem was also the wrong jvm directory

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a permission problem you should run the following command

```
sudo chmod -R +x tomcat/
```

I followed the directory structure in the tutorial (at digitalocean) you are following. You may replace the tomcat/ dir with you own installation dir

Comment: looks like a bad idea to me... I don't think you want the files inside the directory to be executable, especially not for everyone...

Comment: Well then you can run the command just on the .sh scripts but this solves the problem

Comment: chown -hR user:group tomcat - did the trick for me :)

Answer (score 0):

On executing
    systemctl start tomcat

You'll get `[Your Issue]`

```
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Following above instruction on executing `journalctl -xe` you'll get following result:

```
Tomcat appears to still be running with PID *PROCESS_ID*. Start aborted.
If the following process is not a Tomcat process, remove the PID file and try again:
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root       982     1  0 09:51 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
```

Kill the process using (982 is process ID shown in journalctl's result)

`sudo kill -9 *PROCESS_ID*`

Then execute

`systemctl start tomcat` to start tomact.

**Apache tomcat is up and running.**

But this may disable 802.x supplicant which disables WiFi.

To resolve this, execute

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

At least in *Ubuntu* and other OS (like *CentOS*), I got this problem was related to execution permissions for the scripts in the `bin` folder.  In this case, apart from changing the owner to the user `tomcat`, you have to provide execution permissions to the scripts in the `${TOMCAT}/bin` folder, in particular to the `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` scripts.  Assuming the Tomcat package has been extracted in `/opt/tomcat`, then:

```
sudo chmod 755 /opt/tomcat/bin/*.sh
```

After that

```
sudo systemctl start tomcat
```